# Sec-Fetch-Mode and blocked CORS

Tags: google-chrome, cors, http-status-code-400, sec-fetch-site, sec-fetch-mode

So I have the same website making the same request to the same server on (1) Chrome 76 and (2) Chrome 77 from different networks and computers.

One request has (1) `Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors, Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site` and the other one (2) `Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors, Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site`.
The one with `no-cors` fails with a 400 to a C# Web API endpoint with CORS enabled (for years and thousands of different users on all kinds of devices).

What is going on? There is talk of a Chrome [bug](https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-fetch-metadata/issues/35) not sending that header for pre-flight, but there it is and set to `no-cors`.

Security setting or bug in Chrome? Fixable server-side or front-end-side?

**This is sent by an XMLHttpRequest, not the new Fetch-API.**

Comment: Check if [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/fetch-metadata/#sec-fetch-mode-header) information could be helpful

Comment: Yes, but I don't believe there is any control using XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: Hi did you manage to solve it? I'm having similar issue.

Comment: I stopped having this problem. It might have been an interim issue in Chrome with the configurations I was running. If you run into this now it's likely just a bad CORS setup.